# Epanechnikov function equivalence in R

Tags: r, bandwidth

I've got a question about if there are any equivalent functions that use the Epanechnikov kernel as an estimator. So for example, I have some code where I use the "dnorm" and "dunif" functions as kernels for the normal kernel and boxcar kernel respectively within r. Is there a similar function in base R or will I just have to create a function to handle the Epanechnikov kernel as I have not been able to find any functions?

My second question is since the Epanechnikov kernel is defined from -1 to 1 for k(u)=3/4(1-u^2), how would my function work for any u value and standardize it into a density such as the dnorm and dunif function? As ultimately I wish to run it through a dataset to try to find the optimal bandwidth using general cross-validation with a few loop statements. An example code using the dunif function is found below,

```
Data=read.table(paste0("http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry",
                   "/all-of-nonpar/=data/lidar.dat"),
            header=TRUE)
x=Data$range
y=Data$logratio
n=length(x)
fit=rep(0,n)
L=rep(0,n)
h=seq(1,40,0.1)
nh=length(h)
UniGCV=rep(0,nh)
UniCV=rep(0,nh)
for (k in 1:nh){
  for (i in 1:n){
   fit[i]=sum(dunif((x[i]-x)/h[k],min=-1, max=1)*y)/ sum(dunif((x[i]-x)/h[k],min=-1, max=1))
   L[i]=dunif(0,min=-1, max=1)/sum(dunif((x[i]-x)/h[k],min=-1, max=1))
  }
  v=sum(L)
  UniGCV[k]=sum((y-fit)^2)*n/((n-v)^2)
  UniCV[k]=sum((y-fit)^2/(1-L)^2)/n
}
UniGCV
plot(h,UniGCV, type="p", lty=1, col="red")
Unihgcv=h[UniGCV==min(UniGCV)]
min(Unihgcv)
```

Now using this code I get that the general cross-validation optimal bandwidth using the uniform/boxcar kernel is 27. And this is the same thing I wish to do using the Epanechnikov kernel.

Note: I've already done this for a normal kernel using the dnorm function and I'm trying to avoid using any necessary packages. Also, anything with UniCv can be ignored for now.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to this, I managed to find a source which provides a psudeocode function for the Epanechnikov as,

```
KEpa = function(z, h = 1) 3 / (4 * h) * (1 - (z / h)^2) * (abs(z) < h)
```

Adjusting my code I get,

```
                   "/all-of-nonpar/=data/lidar.dat"),
            header=TRUE)
x=Data$range
y=Data$logratio
n=length(x)
fit=rep(0,n)
L=rep(0,n)
h=seq(1,40,0.1)
nh=length(h)
UniGCV=rep(0,nh)
UniCV=rep(0,nh)
KEpa = function(z, h = 1) 3 / (4 * h) * (1 - (z / h)^2) * (abs(z) < h)
for (k in 1:nh){
  for (i in 1:n){
   ffit[i]=sum(KEpa((x[i]-x)/h[k])*y)/ sum(KEpa((x[i]-x)/h[k]))
   L[i]=KEpa(0)/sum(KEpa((x[i]-x)/h[k]))
  }
  v=sum(L)
  UniGCV[k]=sum((y-fit)^2)*n/((n-v)^2)
  UniCV[k]=sum((y-fit)^2/(1-L)^2)/n
}
UniGCV
plot(h,UniGCV, type="p", lty=1, col="red")
Unihgcv=h[UniGCV==min(UniGCV)]
min(Unihgcv)
```

Which upon running gives me an optimal bandwidth of around 30, which is near 27 I get when using the uniform kernel and the desired result. I'm sure the code can be optimized however for now this will work.